# Could not find service of type 'TrainingApprovalSiteWorkflow.ITrainingSiteCreationService

Tags: 2010

[System.InvalidOperationException] = {"Could not find service of type 'TrainingApprovalSiteWorkflow.ITrainingSiteCreationService' through the currently configured services. Consider adding the service to ExternalDataExchangeService."}

According to the book I had to add, this to web.config

```
<WorkflowService Assembly="TrainingApprovalSiteWorkFlow, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=ec95eb8ee603c598" Class="TrainingApprovalSiteWorkflow.TrainingSiteCreationService">
  </WorkflowService>
```

However I am not sure if I did to the correct web.config there are so many
I added to inetpub\80\web.config
Is it there or some other web.config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add this to the web.config file of the web application you are targeting with your plugable Worflow service.

Just open the intemgr and look for your web application. Once you locate the one you are looking for, you can right click on the same and select **Explore**.

There you will find the web.config file which you need to edit.